# How does (this) overriding tostring method for LinkedList class work?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, tostring

I have created a `class Test` storing `class Pair` objects in linkedlist data structure defined in the library .  To print the `Pair` class objects I have overridden method in pair class and it works as shown below -

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Test{
    static LinkedList<Pair> list=new LinkedList<Pair>();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        list.add(new Pair(31,78));
        list.add(new Pair(89,67));
        list.add(new Pair(90,43));

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

class Pair{
    int x;
    int y;
    Pair(int m, int n){
        x=m;
        y=n;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{ "+ this.x + ", " +this.y+" }";
    }
}
```

The output -

```
[{ 2, 4 }, { 6, 3 }, { 12, 6 }]
```

My doubt is regarding the `toString()` method-

- What happens internally when I print a Linked List ?
- If I would have stored some integers in a linked list, would Integer class toString() method would have been called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `LinkedList<E>.toString()` is inherited from `AbstractCollection<E>`; it's [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) like this:

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters `", "` (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by `String.valueOf(Object)`.

So `String.valueOf` is called on each element - which in turn will call `Object.toString()` for any non-null element. In your case, you've overridden that in `Pair`, so that's what's called.

If you add some logging in `Pair.toString`, like this:

```
public String toString(){
    String ret = "{ "+ this.x + ", " +this.y+" }";
    System.out.println("toString called: returning " + ret;
    return ret;
}
```

... you can see it being called (or you could use a debugger). And yes, if the list contained integers, the list's string representation would be "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" or whatever. (It's possible that `String.valueOf` is optimized to handle numeric types directly, but *logically* it would call the `toString()` override in `Integer`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code for LinkedList:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java

Which (after a few steps) ends up implementing AbstractCollection

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java

And as you can see the source code for `toString` is here:

```java
    public String toString() {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return "[]";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for (;;) {
            E e = it.next();
            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
            if (! it.hasNext())
                return sb.append(']').toString();
            sb.append(',').append(' ');
        }
    }
```

Now we need to find out what `StringBuilder` does when adding `e` using `.append()`

Which is found in the StringBuilder source

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/StringBuilder.java

```java
    @Override
    public StringBuilder append(Object obj) {
        return append(String.valueOf(obj));
    }
```

And now the question is, what does `String.valueOf` do?

Here is the source:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

```java
    public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

So the answer to your question is: Yes, it would have called `Integer`'s `toString` method.

Answer (score 0):

> Does object class uses the end class's toString() method to print

No, the `println` method calls the `list` objects `toString()` method.

The `LinkedList` has a `toString()` implementation that calls the `toString()` method of all the objects in the list to build the `[item1, item2, ...]` string.

Which of course means that your `toString()` method is called by `LinkedList`, not by `Object` class.

> If I would have stored some integers in a linked list, would `Integer` class `toString()` method would have been called?

Yes.